# Load the `Col"A"` values which falls between dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I looked around and searched on google to find a solution but all in vain. That is i want to load the `Col"A"` (Col"A" values will always be unique) values which falls between dates.

I tried with `Countifs` and `sumifs` but both are for different purpose any help will be appreciated.

Here is the attached picture with result.

[image]

Comment: This looks an awefull lot like Google Sheets instead of Excel... you sure about your tags?

Comment: Yes it is just the example which i created on Google Sheets.

Comment: what means "load" ?

Comment: you sample screenshot is nearly perfectly set to use Data/Avanced Filter

Comment: Yes you are right. But for this i have to use VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sequence is not important, you can use `AGGREGATE`:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,A:A*(B:B>=$F$2)*(B:B<=$G$2),ROW(A1))
```

else use `INDEX`:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A:A)/((B:B>=$F$2)*(B:B<=$G$2)),ROW(A1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much i was desperately looking for the solution. Is there any way to hide `0` and `#NUM!`

Comment: @Valiant For ```#NUM``` use ```IFERROR```, for ```0``` use ```IF```

Comment: @Valiant Try to change full column reference with used range, i.e. ```A:A``` -> ```A1:A1000```and so on. If that doesn't help, then think of a VBA

Comment: I posted a question please help. [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67438607/filter-and-copy-paste-the-values-vba)